# How can I transfer photos from the Camera Roll to Photo Stream?

Tags: icloud, photo-stream, camera

Not all of my photos go to Photo Stream, some still go to my Camera Roll.  I'm trying to get them on my Photo Stream so they will be on iCloud.
With 30 photos on my camera, 10 in stream, I took 6 photos.  2 appeared in stream, 4 did not.  Some of my subsequent photos also appeared in the stream, but not all.  This is arbitrary behavior by the program.  How to fix?  Assume ios 7.0.

Comment: Are these pictures you are taking? What hardware? What software version?

Answer (score 3):

Any photos that exist in the Camera Roll that didn't come from the device itself had to come from another device. The primary method for getting these pictures into iCloud's 1000 picture buffer is to enroll that other device into iCloud.

You have one case of a picture that was taken either more than 30 days ago or 1000 pictures ago or you deleted your entire Photo Stream and want to start over. In this case, you may need to sync those photos to a computer or another device using the [Camera Connecton Kit](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC531ZM/A) to inject them into your current Photo Stream.

Comment: Within iPhoto you can select the photos you want to send to iCloud. Select the images you want to send then use the Share button or menu to send to Photo Stream.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to any picture in your Camera Roll, select it and then copy it by pressing the Home button and the Sleep button. This will make a screenshot of the picture in your Camera Roll and send that up to iCloud.

With iOS 6 you can select photos from your camera roll and share them to a personal photo stream to yourself.

Comment: This is a viable option if you want to push a screen resolution png version of photo. In some cases, this is enough capacity, but I have photos in my Camera Roll taken from iPhone 4S as well as DSLR cameras that far exceed the screen resolution of any iOS device and this conversion loses significant picture data as well as the metadata associated with the original. It's a nice trick for something you want to email or when the conversion isn't going to be a downside.

Comment: This isn't 'copying' anything, it's taking a screenshot of the image on your phone.

Comment: You're right and it does say that. It doesn't say it's transferring the image. But it does get a representation of the image to the Photo Stream.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the photos you are looking for are in the stream, but just ordered differently than you expected. For example on my iphone I imported some images from mail. Because the pictures had been taken a while ago they were at the top of the stream instead of the bottom, where I expected them to be. The stream orders them by date taken, where as the camera roll orders them by date imported.

Answer (score 0):

From iPhoto or Aperture, copy the photo you want or drag into the Photostream folder on the sidebar